# How to use multi-threading on Hololens

Tags: c#, multithreading, unity-game-engine, hololens

We're trying to use multi-threading on the Hololens, but fail.
Since we do not know how and what to implement in the additional threads.

Currently our App is running to many operations in the main-thread that if we start our "live-stream" (working with WebcamTexture) the Holograms don't appear anymore.

So to start of with we want to ask how could we use threads run parts of our photocapture-code (seen below) more efficiently? So we can understand which parts to run in different threads.

We're using Unity 2018.4.10f1

```cs
using UnityEngine;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEngine.XR.WSA.WebCam;

public partial class PhotocaptureFrame : MonoBehaviour
{

    public PhotoCapture photoCaptureObject = null;
    public GameObject quad;

    public static PhotocaptureFrame Instance { get; set; }

    private Texture2D imageTexture;
    private CameraParameters c;
    private Resolution cameraResolution;

    private void Start()
    {
        cameraResolution = PhotoCapture.SupportedResolutions.OrderByDescending((res) => res.width * res.height).First();

        PhotoCapture.CreateAsync(false, delegate (PhotoCapture captureObject)
        {
            photoCaptureObject = captureObject;

            //CameraParameters c = new CameraParameters();
            c.hologramOpacity = 0.0f;
            c.cameraResolutionWidth = cameraResolution.width;
            c.cameraResolutionHeight = cameraResolution.height;
            c.pixelFormat = CapturePixelFormat.BGRA32;

            captureObject.StartPhotoModeAsync(c, delegate (PhotoCapture.PhotoCaptureResult result)
            {
                photoCaptureObject.TakePhotoAsync(OnCapturedPhotoToMemory);
            });

        });

        Instance = this;
    }

    public void MakePhoto()
    {
        PhotoCapture.CreateAsync(false, delegate (PhotoCapture captureObject)
{
    photoCaptureObject = captureObject;

    captureObject.StartPhotoModeAsync(c, delegate (PhotoCapture.PhotoCaptureResult result)
    {
        photoCaptureObject.TakePhotoAsync(OnCapturedPhotoToMemory);
    });

});

    }

    public void OnCapturedPhotoToMemory(PhotoCapture.PhotoCaptureResult result, PhotoCaptureFrame photoCaptureFrame)
    {

        Resolution cameraResolution = PhotoCapture.SupportedResolutions.OrderByDescending((res) => res.width * res.height).First(); // Create our Texture2D for use and set the correct resolution
        Texture2D targetTexture = new Texture2D(cameraResolution.width, cameraResolution.height);

        photoCaptureFrame.UploadImageDataToTexture(targetTexture);  // Copy the raw image data into our target texture

        imageTexture = targetTexture;       //Save image to new Texture to not loose it

        quad.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.mainTexture = imageTexture;     // Do as we wish with the texture such as apply it to a material, etc.
                                                                               //photoCaptureObject.StopPhotoModeAsync(OnStoppedPhotoModeEnd);


        // Clean up
        photoCaptureObject.StopPhotoModeAsync(OnStoppedPhotoModeEnd);
    }

    public void OnStoppedPhotoModeEnd(PhotoCapture.PhotoCaptureResult result)
    {
        photoCaptureObject.Dispose();
        photoCaptureObject = null;
        Debug.Log("Photo object disposed.");

    }
}
```

Our expected output is to know which chunks we can run in different threads and how to call different threads on Hololens.

Thanks allot and every help is appreciated.

Comment: I feel like this question is a little too close to asking either for a tutorial on threading or for a refactoring of your code to optimize your thread usage. I would suggest reading a few tutorials on the subject instead of relying on this site. If you get stuck on a particular aspect of threading, that would be a more appropriate question here. Take a look at this: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/understanding-threading-in-net-framework/ and this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/threads-and-threading and the related articles linked  from it.

Comment: Isn't most of stuff done **async** here anyway so on a thread? The texture cration etc can't be done in a thread (at least not using the `Texture2D` library) ... Btw you know that here `imageTexture = targetTexture;       //Save image to new Texture to not loose it` you are actually not creating a new texture but just store a reference, right?

Comment: One thing though: There is no need to dispatch the `photoCaptureObject` and recreate it everytime. Just create it once and never destroy it this saves some resources...

Answer (score 2):

Although this does not directly answer your question, i can really recommed this plugin: [HololensCameraStream](https://github.com/VulcanTechnologies/HoloLensCameraStream) which internally uses the `MediaCapture` class.
Frames are aquired asynchronously meaning the Videocapture itself essentially runs in its own thread. Additionally, performance is better (you can get more frames) compared to your approach with `PhotoCapture`.
You will get each frame in a callback function.

As this callback does not run on the Unity Main Thread, you will need to utilize some kind of job system to then call your Unity functions. I use this handy script: https://github.com/PimDeWitte/UnityMainThreadDispatcher

If this helps and you got further questions, i can add more details on how to set this up.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend that you use the [`MediaCapture`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.capture.mediacapture) class asynchronously for video stream capture. In the actual example, the [HoloLensCamera](https://github.com/microsoft/MixedReality-SpectatorView/blob/394dc7ac4c3d30482c873374ac28c446ebfdff84/src/SpectatorView.Unity/Assets/PhotoCapture/Scripts/HoloLensCamera.cs) class in Microsoft [SpectatorView](https://github.com/microsoft/MixedReality-SpectatorView) uses the MediaCapture class to access video stream from the HoloLens camera. On line [861](https://github.com/microsoft/MixedReality-SpectatorView/blob/394dc7ac4c3d30482c873374ac28c446ebfdff84/src/SpectatorView.Unity/Assets/PhotoCapture/Scripts/HoloLensCamera.cs#L861), it declares an instance of the MediaCapture class and asynchronously obtains the video frame from the camera in the next code.

Answer (score 0):

```
        Texture2D targetTexture = new Texture2D(cameraResolution.width, cameraResolution.height);

        ...

        quad.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.mainTexture = imageTexture;
```

You can only create and assign textures on the main thread in Unity. The correct and only solution is to investigate `WebCamTexture`. You probably ran into a permissions issue.

Comment: Hey Thanks, we tried some stuff and ran exactly into that issue. Sadly it didn't work with `WebCamTexture`, because it's also part of the Unity API therefore being processed on the main thread. But maybe i'm mistaken.

Comment: Carefully read the docs, if you follow their examples exactly you will get an accelerated live stream from the webcam.